# Android support v4 SwipeRefreshLayout empty view issue

Tags: android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

SwipeRefresh is not working after setting an empty view for listview which is the only child of a SwipeRefresh layout. How to solve this issue?

Comment: I have found the solution. We need to set android:clickable(true) for an empty view then it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the XML of your layout? I'm facing the same problem and can't seem to have it work with your solution.

Comment: I have added empty view, But I cannot swipe down this empty view to refresh. Can I get the solution for this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dinesh, you should post your solution as an answer and accept it - that's a common SO practice. Ideally, with xml example.

Comment: Please see my solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40466223/6608860), It should work for this case as well.

Answer (score 23):

Here is the solution:
You can simply use this view hierarchy :

```
    <FrameLayout ...>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout ...>

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list" ... />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty" ...
            android:text="@string/empty_list"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Then, in code, you just call:

```
_listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
```

That's it.

Comment: Nice, upvoted.  But I have one more problem facing, which is  I cannot swipe down this empty view to refresh. isn't it..  Can I get the solution for this.. Thanks in advance. @nitesh

Comment: you need to override canChildScrollUp() method which is in SwipeRefreshLayout class .check my answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236650/swiperefreshlayout-in-android/23679420#23679420.This is for scroll view but you can put some logic for your own view

Comment: If you're gonna take someone else's answer and use it as yours at least give them the credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23424655/893130

Comment: @niteshgoel please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434071/android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout-working-but-it-is-not-visible

Comment: @nitesh goel: I also facing the same problem that was faced by Ashok when using this solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue too, and solved it **without any additional code in the activity** by using the layout below.

If you are using a `ListActivity` or `ListFragment` it handles showing/hiding the empty view for you, and refreshing works with an empty list as well with this layout structure.

No hacks needed, everything is in the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, as it should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Refresher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null" />
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="Geen formulieren gevonden"
                style="@style/text.EmptyView" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Hope this helps you. If so, don't forget to accept the answer.

Note: this is a duplicate of [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818097/android-swiperefreshlayout-with-empty-textview-not-working-properly/31448926#31448926), but that question is pretty much a duplicate of this question... :)

**UPDATE**
If the SwipeRefreshLayout is activated too early, you can implement ListView.OnScroll with:

```
_refresher.Enabled = e.FirstVisibleItem == 0;
```

This disables the refresher until you scrolled to the top. This is only needed when using a ListView, the new RecyclerView works as expected.

Comment: for me it's causing problems with scrolling

Comment: What problems exactly? Have you implemented the viewholder pattern?

Comment: Yes I did. The problem was, that when scrolling list down the swipe-refresh was being activated too early. CustomSwipeRefreshLayout described below works properly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem for me was that when the empty view was visible then the refreshing circle wasn't shown although the refreshing method worked. For me this code worked, I hope it helps.

- the xml layout:

  ```
  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:clickable="true">

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:fadingEdge="none"
          android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
          android:headerDividersEnabled="false"/>

      <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:gravity="center">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/empty_view"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:visibility="gone"/>
      </ScrollView>
  </FrameLayout>
  ```
- the custom SwipeRefreshLayout:

  ```
  package misc;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
      private ListView mListView;

      public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
          super(context);
      }

      public void setListView(ListView listView) {
          mListView = listView;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
          if (mListView == null) {
              return true;
          }

          return mListView.canScrollVertically(-1);
      }
  }
  ```
- and in my Fragment where I use the layout I only set the swipe to refresh layout in this way:

  ```
  mSwipeRefreshLayout.setListView(mListView);
  ```
- the ListView's empty view is set in this way:

  ```
  TextView emptyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
  emptyView.setText("No data");
  mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
  ```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

here's how i did this (probably not very elegant solution)

```
private void createEmptyView() {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) listView.getParent();
    emptyView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater(null)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_empty, parent, false);
    parent.addView(emptyView);
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
}

public class FrameSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private ViewGroup listView;
    public void setListView(ViewGroup list) {
        listView = list;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (listView != null) {
            View child = listView.getChildAt(0);
            return child != null && child.getTop() != 0;
        }
        return super.canChildScrollUp();
    }
}
```

empty layout

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:clickable="true" />
```

list layout

```
    <FrameSwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I like this solution better than 2 SwipeRefreshLayouts as I have only one SRL to take care of.

Comment: @orium please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434071/android-support-v4-widget-swiperefreshlayout-working-but-it-is-not-visible

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this issue. I posted a work around solution.

[Android - SwipeRefreshLayout with empty textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964934/android-swiperefreshlayout-with-empty-textview/23025336#23025336)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using two SwipeToRefreshLayouts.

- One for wrapping the ListView
- The other as an emptyView

I posted my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/AndroidExamples/SwipeRefreshLayout-ListViewExample).

Comment: This worked but my ListView is not clickable anymore.

Comment: I moved the SwipeToRefreshLayout for the emptyView above the  SwipeToRefreshLayout for the ListView and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dinesh written above, i have used `clickable="true"` like below with empty `RecyclerView`:

```
mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mRecyclerView.setClickable(true);
myText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshKartvizitKisilerim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/noListItem"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`RecyclerView` has height `match_parent` and `SwipeRefresh` has `wrap_content`. When there is item in list, don't forget to make text `gone`.

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea which works well. 
Subclass **ListView** and override **setAdapter()** and **setEmptyView()**.
**setEmptyView** should just store the view to use for the empty view, and 
**setAdapter** should register a **DataSetObserver** that will hide/show the empty view without altering the list view's visibility. You would probably want to use a  **FrameLayout** that holds your **SwipeToRefreshLayout** and an empty view (as siblings). You can then position the empty view at the top/middle/bottom etc pretty easily using gravity and layout gravity. You could also use a **RelativeLayout** but I haven't tried. You will want to somehow unregister the dataSetObserver, I believe you may want to do that in onDetachFromWindow as I did below.

```
public class SwipeToRefreshCompatibleList extends ListView {

    private boolean mIsEmpty = false;
    private View mEmptyView;
    private Adapter mAdapter;

    private DataSetObserver mLocalObserver = new  DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            boolean isEmpty = mAdapter == null || mAdapter.getCount() == 0;
            if (mEmptyView != null) {
                if (isEmpty != mIsEmpty) {
                    mEmptyView.setVisibility(isEmpty ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            }
            mIsEmpty = isEmpty;
        }
    };

    public SwipeToRefreshCompatibleList(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeToRefreshCompatibleList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SwipeToRefreshCompatibleList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SwipeToRefreshCompatibleList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mLocalObserver);
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void setEmptyView(View view) {
        mEmptyView = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mLocalObserver);
        }
    }

}
```

Example layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <com.company.widget.SwipeToRefreshCompatibleList
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/BasicList"
                android:divider="@null"
                />


        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

While this takes a bit more code than simply subclassing ListView and altering setVisibility such that it won't set the list to GONE/HIDDEN, I feel like this is less of a hack and still allows the user to set the list to GONE/Hidden if they needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried UI hack but it didn't work, the only solution worked is set adapter.
pass empty value make sure the value will not be null.

```
NotificationListAdapter notificationListAdapter;
notificationListAdapter = new NotificationListAdapter(mContext,notificationResponse);
reCycleViewNotificationList.setAdapter(notificationListAdapter); // weather ListView or RecyclerView
```