# SwipeRefreshLayout + WebView when scroll position is at top

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to use SwipeRefreshLayout with WebView.

I'm facing the problem where in the middle of page, when user scrolls down, unwanted refresh kicks in.

How do I make the refresh event only happen when webview's scroll position is at the top. (ie, he's looking at the top portion of the page)?

Comment: I did some testing and I can confirm that this issue still exists on some web pages. Hence fix is required.

Answer (score 38):

I've managed to solve it without having to extend anything. Have a look at this snippet (Fragment-specific):

```
private ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    swipeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener =
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    if (mWebView.getScrollY() == 0)
                        swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
                    else
                        swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);

                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    swipeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
    super.onStop();
}
```

For a broader context, have a look at my answer to [Android - SwipeRefreshLayout with empty textview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27903720/515423).

Comment: One-liner of the poor man (with lambda): `swipeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> swipeLayout.setEnabled((webView.getScrollY() == 0)));`

Comment: Free one liner for Kotlin `swipeRefreshLayout.isEnabled = webView.scrollY == 0`

Comment: Using this solution sometimes flickers the webview while scrolling or fling.

Answer (score 25):

I think the recommended way of doing this is to extend the `SwipeRefreshLayout` and override `canChildScrollUp()` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#canChildScrollUp()

This is how it's done in the Google IO 2014 Schedule app - https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/MultiSwipeRefreshLayout.java#L76

The `CustomSwipeRefreshLayout` will probably look like:

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private CanChildScrollUpCallback mCanChildScrollUpCallback;

    public interface CanChildScrollUpCallback {
        boolean canSwipeRefreshChildScrollUp();
    }

    public void setCanChildScrollUpCallback(CanChildScrollUpCallback canChildScrollUpCallback) {
        mCanChildScrollUpCallback = canChildScrollUpCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (mCanChildScrollUpCallback != null) {
            return mCanChildScrollUpCallback.canSwipeRefreshChildScrollUp();
        }
        return super.canChildScrollUp();
    }
}
```

And in your `Activity` that has the `WebView`,

```
public class FooActivity
        implements CustomSwipeRefreshLayout.CanChildScrollUpCallback {

    private CustomSwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // after initialization
        mRefreshLayout.setCanChildScrollUpCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSwipeRefreshChildScrollUp() {
        return mWebview.getScrollY() > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The real issue is why does `SwipeRefreshLayout` intercepts touch events event when requested not to by scrolling child views. Removing that "feature" would solve all these issues automatically. See the following answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978462/swiperefreshlayout-viewpager-limit-horizontal-scroll-only/25983397#25983397

Comment: mWebView.getScrollY is always 0 for me.

Comment: @JohnShelley Check your web layout. "position: relative;" property in your CSS might be the source of your problem. Relative positioning causes troubles with scrolling in the WebView.

Comment: @petrnohejl but what if we are loading some othe website? we can't have control over other websites, so this is not a global solution

Comment: Unable to start activity, android.view.InflateException

Comment: @PabloCegarra You need to provide some constructors for the custom view. hope it helps others

Answer (score 12):

Just implement your `Fragment` or `Activity` with     `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener` then set Listener like `webview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);`

In `onScrollChanged()` method do like this

```
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        if (webview.getScrollY() == 0) {
            swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, thanks mate

Answer (score 5):

Most recent versions of support library have `SwipeRefreshLayout#setOnChildScrollUpCallback` method which allows you to avoid subclassing `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

```
mBinding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnChildScrollUpCallback((parent, child) -> 
            mBinding.webView.getScrollY() > 10);
```

Comment: I used 
`swipeRefreshLayout.setOnChildScrollUpCallback((p, c) -> webview.getScrollY() > 0);`
and there's no need to extend SwipeRefreshLayout for
`androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

It works for API >= 23 Android Marshmallow

```
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(scrollY == 0);
        }
    });
```

**Edit 1:**
This is not working if web page has nested scrolling content. So instead of using SwipeRefreshLayout I decided to use simple ImageButton to reload web page.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by extending SwipeRefreshLayout with a custom SwipeRefreshLayout that takes in the WebView and use the WebView to check the scrollY position.

Note: 
This will work for scrolling the whole page, but it may not work with nested scrolls.
Also, if you have horizontal scrolling you may also want to add the logic found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453194

```
public class CustomSwipeToRefresh extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private final int yScrollBuffer = 5;
    private WebView mWebView;

    public CustomSwipeToRefresh(Context context, WebView webView) {
        super(context);

        mWebView = webView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mWebView.getScrollY() > yScrollBuffer)
            return false;

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you purpose it work with nested scrolls? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering the same question but using Kotlin. By enabling `swipeRefreshLayout` when the scrollY of `webView` gets `0`:

Make this variable in your fragment or activity:

```
private val onScrollChangedListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener{ swipeRefreshLayout.isEnabled = webView.scrollY == 0 }
```

Then `onViewCreated`:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener)
```

Then `onStop`:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener)
```

*From here everything will work well. But if the webpage your are using has a fixed header that does not scroll `scrollY` will always be equal to `0`. And this solution together with other solution in this page may not work.*

Comment: Your comment about fixed header definitely saved me a lot of time debugging!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing Similar issue but none of the answers given here works for me. So, I got a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753235/5996106) answer.

**Step 1** : Create Class **`CustomWebView`**

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView{

private OnScrollChangedCallback mOnScrollChangedCallback;

public CustomWebView(final Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public CustomWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt)
{
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    if(mOnScrollChangedCallback != null) mOnScrollChangedCallback.onScroll(l, t);
}

public OnScrollChangedCallback getOnScrollChangedCallback()
{
    return mOnScrollChangedCallback;
}

public void setOnScrollChangedCallback(final OnScrollChangedCallback onScrollChangedCallback)
{
    mOnScrollChangedCallback = onScrollChangedCallback;
}

/**
 * Impliment in the activity/fragment/view that you want to listen to the webview
 */
public static interface OnScrollChangedCallback
{
    public void onScroll(int horizontal, int vertical);
}}
```

**Step 2** : In **xml** file use `webview` like this-

```
 <com.yourpackagename.CustomWebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Step 3** : In your `MainActivity` use `setOnScrollChangedCallback` -

```
  mWebView.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new CustomWebView.OnScrollChangedCallback(){
        public void onScroll(int horizontal, int vertical){
            System.out.println("=="+horizontal+"---"+vertical);
   //this is to check webview scroll behaviour
            if (vertical<50){
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by hiBrianLee *almost* worked for me, but as John Shelley wrote, `getScrollY` always returned 0 in my case (I used a `ListView` as the nested scrolling child). What worked straight away, however, was to use `canScrollVertically` instead (which is a `View` method, so it's available both for `ListView`s and `WebView`s, and also for any other kind of scrolling child).

My layout class looks as follows:

```
public class NestedScrollSwipeLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private ListView scrollChild;

    public NestedScrollSwipeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NestedScrollSwipeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollChild(ListView child) {
        this.scrollChild = child;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        return (scrollChild != null && scrollChild.canScrollVertically(-1)) ||
            super.canChildScrollUp();
    }
}
```

(As mentioned, `canScrollVertically` is a `View` method, so the `ListView` can be safely replaced by a general `View` or any other specialized view class.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing above worked for me.Here is my approach

```
 @Override
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {
super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();
 if(y>800){
     swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
 }else {
     swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
 }
 Log.e("yy",""+y);

switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
}

return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
// swipe - active only when WebView Y==0        
swipeView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                if (webView.getScrollY() == 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScrollChanged - y=0 - make swipe refresh active");
                    swipeView.setEnabled(true);
                }else {
                    swipeView.setEnabled(false);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScrollChanged - y is not null - swipe refresh not active");
                }
            }
        });

// swipe - after refresh do work (see above for condition)
    swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            Log.d(TAG, "Swipe - refresh");

            // do work ... your work method here
            getSchedule();

            // hide spinner of swiperefreshlayout
            swipeView.setRefreshing(false);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable approach to solve conflict between `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `WebView`
is to bound touch/swipe gesture to certain space at the top of the screen.

Previous answers base on detecting `webview.scrollY` may be not reliable, because some pages has fixed header position, therefore even if there is scrollable list `webview.scrollY` will alwyas returns 0

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316516/2163045)

1. Create custom `SwipeRefreshLayout`

```
class MySwipeRefreshLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : SwipeRefreshLayout(context, attrs) {

    private var mDeclined = false
    private var mPrevY: Float = 0f

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                mPrevY = event.y

                mDeclined = false
                if (mPrevY > resources.getDimension(R.dimen.disable_swipe_after)){
                    mDeclined = true
                }
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (mDeclined) {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

2. Apply it in the view file

```
    <yourpackage.MyLimitedSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            >

            <WebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
    </yourpackage.MySwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
swipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(webView.getScrollY() == 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This Kotlin code snippet is setting up a SwipeRefreshLayout to enable pull-to-refresh functionality for a WebView in an Android app. It checks the scroll position of the WebView and enables or disables the refresh action based on whether the WebView is scrolled to the top. When the user initiates a refresh, it reloads the WebView content and stops the refreshing animation when done.

```
    binding.swipeRefreshLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
        binding.swipeRefreshLayout.isEnabled = binding.webView.scrollY === 0
    }

    binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
        binding.swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
        binding.webView.reload()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a solution, this will solve the case webView.scrollY == 0 or the web page has nested scrolling content.
The SwipeRefreshLayout  is allowed to intercept the touch event only when the webview is overscroll. Use clampedY to check if the webview is overscrolled.

Step1. Create Class CustomWebView

```
class CustomWebView : WebView {
    
    ....

    override fun onOverScrolled(scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, clampedX: Boolean, clampedY: Boolean) {
        

        // Log.d(TAG, "clampedX $clampedX clampedY $clampedY")
        intercept = clampedY
        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent $event")
        when(event?.action) {
           MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN-> {
              intercept = false
              requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
           }
           MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE-> {
              requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(!intercept)
           }
           else-> {
              requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
           }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
     }
...
}
```

Step2.Create Class CustomSwipeRefreshLayoutUI

```
class CustomSwipeRefreshLayoutUI: SwipeRefreshLayout {
    var disallowIntercept = false
    ....
    
    override fun requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(b: Boolean) {
        disallowIntercept = b
        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(b)
        super.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(b)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // 不允许拦截
        if (disallowIntercept) {
            return false
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }
    ....
    

}
```

The layout file looks like:

```
<yourpackage.CustomSwipeRefreshLayoutUI
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    
    <yourpackage.CustomWebView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
   
</yourpackage.MySwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use SwipeRefreshLayout normally as you do with other views but enable nested scrolling.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thing is once user swipe down too fast it will invoke SwipeReferesh if the user scrolls normally or slowly it is good.

Answer (score -1):

i find a solution for it. Just use the CoordinatorLayout as the root layout and add layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to your SwipeRefreshLayout.It's perfect for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found **disabling** nested scrolling on the **webview** (not the SwipeRefreshLayout itself) sorted this problem for me. It won't be possible to do this in all situations, but was in mine.

```
webView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```