# SwipeRefreshLayout with Tabs and fragments per page has premature pull to refresh functionality

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have setup an app with slidingTabs nested in a swipeRefreshLayout where I have fragments for the pages which have recyclerView lists in them. It works fine but when I scroll down the list and go to scroll back to the top it pulls down the refresh icon before reaching the top again, Im lost as to why...

```
    <com.example.android.ui.widgets.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:foreground="@drawable/header_shadow">

        <!-- Two fragments for the application -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/my_activity_background">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </com.example.android.ui.widgets.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I have followed a lot of the google io app but I can't seem to figure it out, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to override canChildScrollUp() of the SwipeRefreshLayout

I got that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658428/swiperefreshlayout-webview-when-scroll-position-is-at-top)!