# Android Webview SwipeRefreshLayout area

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I have app android `WebApp` inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Problem is when I scroll down webview,  SwipeRefreshLayout trigers and I am not able to scroll down webview it self. 
My target: SwipeRefreshLayout to triger only from green area but still remain 100% of screen. Green Area is part of webview.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Update Css of the webpage to support `webview touch scroll detect`,
mostly in the case overflow property conflicts with the android swipe refresh layout. You can read further on such issues here: 
[SwipeRefreshLayout + WebView when scroll position is at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658428/swiperefreshlayout-webview-when-scroll-position-is-at-top)
 or you can use webview javascript Bridge for this to resolve.