# How can i add Swipe to Refresh in my WebVIew app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview, android-studio-2.2

I made a news Reader App (WebView). I don't know how to add a pull to refresh in my app. I am a student who just got into programming (Learner/n00b) Anyone here that can kindly let me know what to add or which java class or xml code i have to post here so you can help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwipeRefreshLayout + WebView when scroll position is at top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658428/swiperefreshlayout-webview-when-scroll-position-is-at-top)

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your WebView with a `SwipeRefreshLayout`. To do so go to your xml file and do the following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView.../> <!-- your view goes here -->

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Now go to the java file where you have the logic to your WebView (Activity or Fragment) and add the following code:

```
// Swipe to Refresh
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Insert your code here
            webView.reload(); // refreshes the WebView
        }
    });
```

This will set the `OnRefreshListener` and you can add your code on the method. Check out the official documentation as well to see what other methods the `SwipeRefreshLayout` have.

Comment: Is your WebView in your MainActivity or in a Fragment?

Comment: I have a MainActivity Class and and WebViewActivity Class.

Comment: So try to delete the getView() part, if it's still getting an error use getContext() or getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your WebView with a [`SwipeRefreshLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html). Add an `OnRefreshListener` to that `SwipeRefreshLayout` that calls `reload()` on your WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with SwipeRefreshLayout but got confused. This is what helped me: In Android WebViewGold, within Config.java, just turn **ENABLE__PULL_REFRESH** to true – hope this helps :-)