# SwipeRefreshLayout with listview and emptyView

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout, empty-list

i have a SwipeRefreshLayout with a listview, this listview has a emptyview, but when the listview its empty, it show his emptyview, but the refresh on SwipRefreshlayout doesnt work..

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. 
To fix it, you can set the emptyView clickable, like this

```
View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty);
emptyView.setClickable(true);
commentsLV.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

I found this solution in
[Android support v4 SwipeRefreshLayout empty view issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959118/android-support-v4-swiperefreshlayout-empty-view-issue/27247047#27247047(the) first comment).

However, it makes the swipeRefreshlayout can swipe at wrong position.You can fix it by extending swipeRefreshlayout, or reference this [SwiperefreshLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236650/swiperefreshlayout-in-android/23679420#23679420.This)

If you want a convenient solution while using swiperefreshlayout, you can put your listview and emptyview in a framelayout and decide the visibility of emprtyview in your code.